# Where are desktop menus filed?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I am wishing to look at the .desktop files associated with my main menu panel.  I am using gnome on ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2):

System wide files are in:

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

And user only ones in:

```
~/.local/share/applications/
```